# Variable access in gunicorn with multiple workers

Tags: python, gunicorn

Is it possible to have multiple workers running with Gunicorn and have them accessing some global variable in an ordered manner i.e. without running into problems with race conditions?

Comment: ben - what did you find out?  I'm having a similar problem.  I noticed you didn't ever mark this as answered, but I wondered how it turned out

Comment: It has been a while but as far as I remember I concluded that it is not possible to share data between different workers. I mean in the end these are just processes so there are of course ways to share data but it's not straight forward. For my problem it was possible to push the synchronization down to the database level.

Comment: thats what i had done in the meanwhile :/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by global variable, you mean another process that keeps them in memory or on disk, yes I think so. I haven't checked the source code of Gunicorn, but based on a problem I had with some old piece of code was that several users retrieved the same key from a legacy MyISAM table, incrementing it and creating a new entry using it assuming it was unique to create a new record. The result was that occasionally (when under very heavy traffic) one record is created (the newest one overwriting the older ones, all using the same incremented key). This problem was never observed during a hardware upgrade, when I reduced the gunicorn workers of the website to one, which was the reason to explore this probable cause in the first place.

Now usually, reducing the workers will degrade performance, and it is better to deal with these issues with transactions (if you are using an ACID RDBMS, unlike MyISAM). The same issue should be present with in Redis and similar stores.

Also this shouldn't a problem with files and sockets, since to my knowledge, the operating system will block other processes (even children) from accessing an open file.